# ¿Cómo agregar automáticamente la hora en hh:mm:ss cuando se inserta un registro?

Tags: postgresql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
CREATE TABLE cuenta ( 
    codigo_cuenta integer NOT NULL,
    cuenta_clave varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    cuenta_rol varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    cuenta_fecha_registro date NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    cuenta_hora_registro time NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME,
    cuenta_estado integer NOT NULL
);
```

En la columna `cuenta_hora_registro`, la hora se guarda de la siguiente manera: `11:40:30.729922`, y yo deseo que se guarde en formato de Hora:Minuto:Segundo. ¿Cómo puedo lograr esto?

Comment: Es mejor que se diga guardando así, cuando lo selecciones tu motor de bases de datos tiene funciones para formatear la salida como hora minuto y segundo

Comment: `cuenta_hora_registro` es un `TIME`, no tiene ningún formato, no puedes cambiar nada, de hecho internamente el dato `TIME`  es simplemente un numero. El formato aplica a una cadena o la representación de un determinado dato.

Comment: Entonces en ese caso, ¿podrían colocar como respuesta una forma para poder formatearlo en la salida?, ya sea en SQL o Java.

Comment: Prueba con `to_char(cuenta_hora_registro, 'HH24:MI:SS')`